# iOS: Backup core data database in iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, sdk, icloud

I did some research but all I could find was syncing data core with iCloud. I need to know if it is possible / recommended to backup a core data in iCloud. I have an app which uses data core to store information. I would like to have some kind of backup implemented for whenever the user decides to reformat his phone..get a new phone..etc. Is iCloud the way to go ? We already implemented export to CSV and we're planning to implement import from CSV. I was just wondering if iCloud was a solution for backing up core data once a day lets say..or smth like that. Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what iCloud is for. You can implement it, then when the user moves to a new device, all the data is there for them. It's not really a backup solution though, in the way you're thinking about it, the user doesn't really have access to a file they can copy to a USB stick. It's a way to have the data available to all devices and to move the data to new devices. It doesn't backup once a day, it backs up at more regular intervals. It works well with Core Data too, loading the updates asynchronously, only sending delta updates through the network, syncing quickly over WiFi. Check out the WWDC 2011 session 303 video or [Using Core Data with iCloud Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html) and [iCloud Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1).

I don't think it's that easy to implement iCloud with Core Data, they're both complicated to learn, but it will probably save you trouble in the future to use them.

Comment: Ok I get it. It works like iCloud works with any other app. just invisible to the user. thats exactly what I need. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's great. Good luck with learning and implementing iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to iCloud as well but as far as I understood it a pure backup should be possible:

There are different possibilities but at the bottom your core data implementation will most likely use a SQLite file to store its data. To create a backup of this file simply copy it to a location inside the iCloud directory (the directory specified by the URL you get from URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier.

As pointed out before I am new to that topic too. Thus there is a good chance that I am talking nonsense. But if I am not, it might be what you are look your and be worth a try.